# if and else if getting error with method return datatable c#

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when I write a method returning a datatable using if and else if statement. what is the correct format. Thanks in advance
"not all code paths return a value"

```
    [HttpGet]
    public DataTable getcareerdata (int tclass, int efkey)
    {
        if (tclass ==7)
        {
            return obj.GetData(string.Format(@"select Effect_Class_Key , From_Value , To_Value , Effect_Class_Value, Scientific_Degree, case When Scientific_Degree  is null then 'Not Related'
            when Scientific_Degree  = 0 then 'Not Related' when Scientific_Degree  = -1 then 'Not Related' else latin_desc  end as Spec from hr_effect_classes Left Outer Join general_cod 
            on hr_effect_classes.Scientific_Degree = general_cod .sub_cod and  main_cod = 17001  where type_class in (7) and status_class = 1  and effect_key = {0}
            Order By  Scientific_Degree  , From_Value ", efkey));
        }
        else if (tclass == 8)
        {
            return obj.GetData(string.Format(@"select Effect_Class_Key ,  From_Value , To_Value , Effect_Class_Value, Scientific_Degree case When Scientific_Degree is null then 'Not Related'
            when Scientific_Degree  = 0 then 'Not Related' when Scientific_Degree  = -1 then 'Not Related' else L_Desc end as Spec from hr_effect_classes Left Outer Join HR_Specialty   
            on hr_effect_classes.Scientific_Degree = HR_Specialty.Spec_Key where type_class in (8) and status_class = 1 and effect_key = {0}
            Order By  Scientific_Degree  , From_Value ",efkey));
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the case where tclass doesn't = 7 or 8, there is no datatable returned. How you handle that depends on what you need.

Comment: do you need a catch-all `else` ?

Comment: You can add a `return null` at the end to avoid that compile error.

Comment: declare a DataTable at the top of your class (outside the if), and then populate that Datatable in the if statement, and do the RETURN outside the if at the bottom.

Comment: I think that you can find thousands of duplicates for this error. Just try to search before posting next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your both if conditions fail then your method has nothing to return while your method signatures telling the compiler that it will return an object of type `DataTable` which it would fail to do so in the case which is stated above.

So, What should be done is use a local variable of type `DataTable` and set it's value accordingly in the conditional blocks and then finally return the variable back from method.

Refactor your method to be like :

```
DataTable table = null;
if (tclass ==7)
{
    table  = obj.GetData(string.Format(@"select Effect_Class_Key , From_Value , To_Value , Effect_Class_Value, Scientific_Degree, case When Scientific_Degree  is null then 'Not Related'
            when Scientific_Degree  = 0 then 'Not Related' when Scientific_Degree  = -1 then 'Not Related' else latin_desc  end as Spec from hr_effect_classes Left Outer Join general_cod 
            on hr_effect_classes.Scientific_Degree = general_cod .sub_cod and  main_cod = 17001  where type_class in (7) and status_class = 1  and effect_key = {0}
            Order By  Scientific_Degree  , From_Value ", efkey));
}
else if (tclass == 8)
{
    table  = obj.GetData(string.Format(@"select Effect_Class_Key ,  From_Value , To_Value , Effect_Class_Value, Scientific_Degree case When Scientific_Degree is null then 'Not Related'
            when Scientific_Degree  = 0 then 'Not Related' when Scientific_Degree  = -1 then 'Not Related' else L_Desc end as Spec from hr_effect_classes Left Outer Join HR_Specialty   
            on hr_effect_classes.Scientific_Degree = HR_Specialty.Spec_Key where type_class in (8) and status_class = 1 and effect_key = {0}
            Order By  Scientific_Degree  , From_Value ",efkey));
}

 return table;
```

Now we are returning a reference of type `DataTable` though it would be null if both conditions fail but it will make your code that compiler takes as valid without any build time errors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to always return something no matter what, so add return null to outside the if statement if neither condition is met.

```
[HttpGet]
public DataTable getcareerdata (int tclass, int efkey)
{
    if (tclass ==7)
    {
        return obj.GetData(string.Format(@"select Effect_Class_Key , From_Value , To_Value , Effect_Class_Value, Scientific_Degree, case When Scientific_Degree  is null then 'Not Related'
        when Scientific_Degree  = 0 then 'Not Related' when Scientific_Degree  = -1 then 'Not Related' else latin_desc  end as Spec from hr_effect_classes Left Outer Join general_cod 
        on hr_effect_classes.Scientific_Degree = general_cod .sub_cod and  main_cod = 17001  where type_class in (7) and status_class = 1  and effect_key = {0}
        Order By  Scientific_Degree  , From_Value ", efkey));
    }
    else if (tclass == 8)
    {
        return obj.GetData(string.Format(@"select Effect_Class_Key ,  From_Value , To_Value , Effect_Class_Value, Scientific_Degree case When Scientific_Degree is null then 'Not Related'
        when Scientific_Degree  = 0 then 'Not Related' when Scientific_Degree  = -1 then 'Not Related' else L_Desc end as Spec from hr_effect_classes Left Outer Join HR_Specialty   
        on hr_effect_classes.Scientific_Degree = HR_Specialty.Spec_Key where type_class in (8) and status_class = 1 and effect_key = {0}
        Order By  Scientific_Degree  , From_Value ",efkey));
    }
return null;
}
```